Customtkinter creating widgets from a loop that reference each other
I have a program that adds entry widgets to a frame along with a button. When I click the button I want to edit further details about the fields that button references. The button always references the last set of fields populated though, which makes sense as I can't assign a unique name to the widget. How do I get the button to link to the set of fields?
class ToplevelWindow(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, uid, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("400x300")
        self.uid = uid
        self.label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text=self.uid)
        self.label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)



class ItemFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, door_list, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        # name / reader
        self.door_list = door_list
        for door in self.door_list:
            print(f'DOOR POS IS {self.door_list.index(door)}')
            self.uid = customtkinter.StringVar()
            self.uid.trace_add('write', self.callback)
            self.door_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Door Name")
            self.door_label.grid(column=0, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3, padx=10, pady=(50, 2.5))
            self.door_name = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text=door, textvariable=self.uid)
            self.door_name.grid(column=1, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3, pady=(50, 2.5))

            self.in_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="In Reader")
            self.in_label.grid(column=2, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3, padx=10, pady=(50, 2.5))
            self.in_reader = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text=door)
            self.in_reader.grid(column=3, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3, pady=(50, 2.5))

            self.out_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Out Reader")
            self.out_label.grid(column=4, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3, padx=10, pady=(50, 2.5))
            self.out_reader = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text=door)
            self.out_reader.grid(column=5, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3, pady=(50, 2.5))


            # zone /controller
            self.con_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Controller")
            self.con_label.grid(column=0, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+1, padx=10, pady=2.5)
            self.con_name = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text=door)
            self.con_name.grid(column=1, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+1)

            self.az_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Access Zone")
            self.az_label.grid(column=2, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+1, padx=10)
            self.az = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text=door)
            self.az.grid(column=3, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+1)

            self.alz_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Alarm Zone")
            self.alz_label.grid(column=4, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+1, padx=10)
            self.alz = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text=door)
            self.alz.grid(column=5, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+1)


            # I/O
            self.dps_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="DPS Name")
            self.dps_label.grid(column=0, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+2, padx=10, pady=2.5)
            self.dpsname = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text="DPS ")
            self.dpsname.grid(column=1, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+2)

            self.rex_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="REX Name")
            self.rex_label.grid(column=2, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+2, padx=10)
            self.rexname = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text="REX ")
            self.rexname.grid(column=3, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+2)

            self.lock_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Lock Name")
            self.lock_label.grid(column=4, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+2, padx=10)
            self.lockname = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text="Lock ")
            self.lockname.grid(column=5, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+2)

            self.save = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Configure I/O", command=lambda: self.open_toplevel(self.uid.get()))
            self.save.grid(column=6, row=self.door_list.index(door)*3+2, padx=5)

        self.toplevel_window = None


    def callback(self, var, indx, mode):
        uid = self.uid.get()
        print(uid)
    def open_toplevel(self, uid):
        if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
            self.toplevel_window = ToplevelWindow(uid=self.uid.get())
            self.toplevel_window.attributes("-topmost", True)
        else:
            self.toplevel_window.focus()

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Gallagher Bulk Import GUI")
        self.geometry("1050x650")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.door_list = []
        self.itemframe = ItemFrame(self, door_list=self.door_list)
        self.itemframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="New Door", command=self.add_door)
        self.button.grid(row=len(itemlist)+25, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

    def add_door(self):
        self.door_list = self.itemframe.door_list
        self.itemframe.destroy()
        numbox = len(self.door_list) + 1
        self.door_list.append("NewDoor" + str(numbox))
        self.itemframe = ItemFrame(self, door_list=self.door_list)
        self.itemframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
        print(self.door_list)

